# Why does cut fail with bash and not zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, quoting, whitespace, here-string

I create a file with tab-delimited fields.

```
echo foo$'\t'bar$'\t'baz$'\n'foo$'\t'bar$'\t'baz > input
```

I have the following script named `zsh.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
while read line; do
    <<<$line cut -f 2
done < "$1"
```

I test it.

```
$ ./zsh.sh input
bar
bar
```

This works fine. However, when I change the first line to invoke `bash` instead, it fails.

```
$ ./bash.sh input
foo bar baz
foo bar baz
```

Why does this fail with `bash` and work with `zsh`?

### Additional troubleshooting

- Using direct paths in the shebang instead of `env` produces the same behaviour.
- Piping with `echo` instead of using the here-string `<<<$line` also produces the same behaviour. i.e. `echo $line | cut -f 2`.
- Using `awk` instead of `cut` *works* for both shells. i.e. `<<<$line awk '{print $2}'`.

Comment: By the way, you can make your test file more simply by doing one of these: `echo -e 'foo\tbar\tbaz\n...'`, `echo $'foo\tbar\tbaz\n...'`, or `printf 'foo\tbar\tbaz\n...\n'` or variations of these. It saves you from having to individually wrap each tab or newline.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What happens is that `bash` replaces the tabs with spaces. You can avoid this problem by saying `"$line"` instead, or by explicitly cutting on spaces.

Comment: Is there any reason Bash sees a `\t` and replaces it with a space?

Comment: @user1717828 yes, it's called the [spit+glob operator](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/22222). It's what happens when you use a variable unquoted in bash and similar shells.

Comment: @terdon, in `<<< $line`, `bash` does split but not glob. There's no reason it would do split here as `<<<` expects a single word. It splits and then joins in that case, which makes little sense and is against all other shells implementations that have supported `<<<` before or after `bash`. IMO it's a bug.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas fair enough, the issue is with the split part anyway.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas No split (nor glob) happens on bash 4.4

Comment: @BinaryZebra, indeed, well spotted. Glad they've fixed it.

Comment: Would help a lot to see the resulting `bash.sh` in the answer

Answer (score 17):

That's because in `<<< $line`, `bash` versions prior to 4.4 did word splitting, (though not globbing) on `$line` when not quoted there and then joined the resulting words with the space character (and put that in a temporary file followed by a newline character and make that the stdin of `cut`).

```
$ a=a,b,,c bash-4.3 -c 'IFS=","; sed -n l <<< $a'
a b  c$
```

`tab` happens to be in the default value of `$IFS`:

```
$ a=$'a\tb'  bash-4.3 -c 'sed -n l <<< $a'
a b$
```

The solution with `bash` is to quote the variable.

```
$ a=$'a\tb' bash -c 'sed -n l <<< "$a"'
a\tb$
```

Note that it's the only shell that does that. `zsh` (where `<<<` comes from, inspired by Byron Rakitzis's implementation of `rc`), `ksh93`, `mksh` and `yash` which also support `<<<` don't do it.

When it comes to arrays, `mksh`, `yash` and `zsh` join on the first character of `$IFS`, `bash` and `ksh93` on space.

```
$ mksh -c 'a=(1 2); IFS=:; sed -n l <<< "${a[@]}"'
1:2$
$ yash -c 'a=(1 2); IFS=:; sed -n l <<< "${a[@]}"'
1:2$
$ ksh -c 'a=(1 2); IFS=:; sed -n l <<< "${a[@]}"'
1 2$
$ zsh -c 'a=(1 2); IFS=:; sed -n l <<< "${a[@]}"'
1:2$
$ bash -c 'a=(1 2); IFS=:; sed -n l <<< "${a[@]}"'
1 2$
```

There's a difference between `zsh`/`yash` and `mksh` (version R52 at least) when `$IFS` is empty:

```
$ mksh -c 'a=(1 2); IFS=; sed -n l <<< "${a[@]}"'
1 2$
$ zsh -c 'a=(1 2); IFS=; sed -n l <<< "${a[@]}"'
12$
```

The behaviour is more consistent across shells when you use `"${a[*]}"` (except that `mksh` still has a bug when `$IFS` is empty).

In `echo $line | ...`, that's the usual split+glob operator in all Bourne-like shells but `zsh` (and the usual problems associated with `echo`).

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you (+1). I'll accept the lowest rep'ed questioner though, since they answered the question perfectly well enough to reveal my stupidity.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you're not quoting `$line`. To investigate, change the two scripts so they simply print `$line`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read line; do
    echo $line
done < "$1"
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
while read line; do
    echo $line
done < "$1"
```

Now, compare their output:

```
$ bash.sh input 
foo bar baz
foo bar baz
$ zsh.sh input 
foo    bar    baz
foo    bar    baz
```

As you can see, because you're not quoting `$line`, the tabs aren't interpreted correctly by bash. Zsh seems to deal with that better. Now, `cut` uses `\t` as the field delimiter by default. Therefore, since your `bash` script is eating the tabs (because of the split+glob operator), `cut` only sees one field and acts accordingly. What you are really running is:

```
$ echo "foo bar baz" | cut -f 2
foo bar baz
```

So, to get your script to work as expected in both shells, quote your variable:

```
while read line; do
    <<<"$line" cut -f 2
done < "$1"
```

Then, both produce the same output:

```
$ bash.sh input 
bar
bar
$ zsh.sh input 
bar
bar
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you (+1). I'll accept the lowest rep'ed questioner though, since they answered the question perfectly well enough to reveal my stupidity.

Comment: ^vote for being the only answer (as yet) to actually include the corrected `bash.sh`

Answer (score 1):

As has already been answered, a more portable way to use a variable is to quote it:

```
$ printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' foo bar baz
foo    bar    baz
$ l="$(printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' foo bar baz)"
$ <<<$l     sed -n l
foo bar baz$

$ <<<"$l"   sed -n l
foo\tbar\tbaz$
```

There is a difference of implementation in bash, with the line:

```
l="$(printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' foo bar baz)"; <<<$l  sed -n l
```

This is the result of most shells:

```
/bin/sh         : foo bar baz$
/bin/b43sh      : foo bar baz$
/bin/bash       : foo bar baz$
/bin/b44sh      : foo\tbar\tbaz$
/bin/y2sh       : foo\tbar\tbaz$
/bin/ksh        : foo\tbar\tbaz$
/bin/ksh93      : foo\tbar\tbaz$
/bin/lksh       : foo\tbar\tbaz$
/bin/mksh       : foo\tbar\tbaz$
/bin/mksh-static: foo\tbar\tbaz$
/usr/bin/ksh    : foo\tbar\tbaz$
/bin/zsh        : foo\tbar\tbaz$
/bin/zsh4       : foo\tbar\tbaz$
```

Only bash split the variable on the right of `<<<` when unquoted.
However, that has been corrected on bash version 4.4
That means that the value of `$IFS` affects the result of `<<<`.

---

With the line:

```
l=(1 2 3); IFS=:; sed -n l <<<"${l[*]}"
```

All shells use the first character of IFS to join values.

```
/bin/y2sh       : 1:2:3$
/bin/sh         : 1:2:3$
/bin/b43sh      : 1:2:3$
/bin/b44sh      : 1:2:3$
/bin/bash       : 1:2:3$
/bin/ksh        : 1:2:3$
/bin/ksh93      : 1:2:3$
/bin/lksh       : 1:2:3$
/bin/mksh       : 1:2:3$
/bin/zsh        : 1:2:3$
/bin/zsh4       : 1:2:3$
```

With `"${l[@]}"`, an space is needed to separate the different arguments, but some shells choose to use the value from IFS (Is that correct?).

```
/bin/y2sh       : 1:2:3$
/bin/sh         : 1 2 3$
/bin/b43sh      : 1 2 3$
/bin/b44sh      : 1 2 3$
/bin/bash       : 1 2 3$
/bin/ksh        : 1 2 3$
/bin/ksh93      : 1 2 3$
/bin/lksh       : 1:2:3$
/bin/mksh       : 1:2:3$
/bin/zsh        : 1:2:3$
/bin/zsh4       : 1:2:3$
```

---

With a null IFS, the values should become joined, as with this line:

```
a=(1 2 3); IFS=''; sed -n l <<<"${a[*]}"

/bin/y2sh       : 123$
/bin/sh         : 123$
/bin/b43sh      : 123$
/bin/b44sh      : 123$
/bin/bash       : 123$
/bin/ksh        : 123$
/bin/ksh93      : 123$
/bin/lksh       : 1 2 3$
/bin/mksh       : 1 2 3$
/bin/zsh        : 123$
/bin/zsh4       : 123$
```

But both lksh and mksh fail to do so.

If we change to a list of arguments:

```
l=(1 2 3); IFS=''; sed -n l <<<"${l[@]}"

/bin/y2sh       : 123$
/bin/sh         : 1 2 3$
/bin/b43sh      : 1 2 3$
/bin/b44sh      : 1 2 3$
/bin/bash       : 1 2 3$
/bin/ksh        : 1 2 3$
/bin/ksh93      : 1 2 3$
/bin/lksh       : 1 2 3$
/bin/mksh       : 1 2 3$
/bin/zsh        : 123$
/bin/zsh4       : 123$
```

Both yash and zsh fail to keep arguments separated. Is that a bug?

Comment: About `zsh`/`yash` and `"${l[@]}"` in non-list context, that's by design where `"${l[@]}"` is only special in list contexts. In non-list contexts, there's no _separation_ possible, you need to join the elements somehow. Joining with the first character of $IFS is more consistent than joining with a space character IMO. `dash` does it as well (`dash -c 'IFS=; a=$@; echo "$a"' x a b`). POSIX however is intending to change that IIRC though. See [this (long) discussion](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/9972)

Comment: See also http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=888 and http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.dash/1179

Comment: Replying to myself, no, having a second look, POSIX will leave the behaviour for `var=$@` unspecified.