# backtick or Here string or read is not working as expected in RHEL 8

Tags: bash, rhel, io-redirection, read, here-string

I am trying to redirect the output of a python script as an input into an interactive shell script.

**test.py**

```
print('Hello')
print('world')
```

Say test.py is as above prints *"Hello world"* which is feed to two variables using **Here string** redirection as below

***Interactive script*** :  `` read a b  <<< `python3 test.py` ``

This is not working as expected in Rhel 8 server while it works fine in Rhel 7

**Rhel 8:**

```
tmp> read a  b  <<< `python3 test.py`
tmp> echo $a $b
Hello
tmp> cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.3 (Ootpa)
```

**variable b is empty** in rhel 8

**Rhel 7:**

```
tmp> read a  b  <<< `python3 test.py`
tmp> echo $a $b
Hello world
tmp> cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 (Maipo)
```

while the **read & Here string** works fine in both cases as below

```
tmp> read a b <<< Hello world"
tmp> echo $a $b
Hello world
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`read a b` reads two words from *one* line (words delimited by `$IFS` characters and word and line delimiters escaped with `\`).

Your `python` script outputs 2 lines.

Older versions of `bash` had a bug in that `cmd <<< $var` or `cmd <<< $(cmd2)` was applying word splitting to the expansion of `$var` and `$(cmd2)` and joining the resulting elements back with spaces do make up the contents of the here-string (see for instance [Why does cut fail with bash and not zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/288934)).

That was fixed in version 4.4 which explains why you don't get what *you* expect any longer.

To read the first two lines of the output of a command into the `$a` and `$b` variable in `bash`, use:

```
{
  IFS= read -r a
  IFS= read -r b
} < <(cmd)
```

Or (not in interactive shells):

```
shopt -s lastpipe
cmd | {
  IFS= read -r a
  IFS= read -r b
}
```

Or without `lastpipe`:

```
cmd | {
  IFS= read -r a
  IFS= read -r b
  something with "$a" and "$b"
}
# $a and $b will be lost after the `{...}` command group returns
```

To join lines of the output of a command with spaces, use: `cmd | paste -sd ' ' -`. Then you can do:

```
IFS=' ' read -r a b < <(cmd | paste -sd ' ' -)
```

If you like.

You can also read the lines into elements an array with:

```
readarray -t array < <(cmd)
```

And join the elements of the array with the first character of `$IFS` (space by default) with `"${array[*]}"`.

Comment: See also: [Split string using IFS](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/397208)