# Return string of a line in a file with multiple line after a matching pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, cat

I have a file with multiple lines in it.
I am trying to get a string that appears after a specific pattern...

Here is the command i am trying to do:

```
sed -n -e 's/^.*DB_PASS=//p' <<< $(cat /root/dadosDB)
```

But instead of giving me only the line i want, its giving me everything after the pattern I specified...

**What I expect:**

Return only the output of the line that contains `DB_PASS` and ignore other lines.

**What the command is doing:**

Printing everything of the entire file after `DB_PASS` and ignoring everything that appears before that pattern.

Any help is apprreciate it!

Here is what I have inside `dadosDB`:

```
DB_USER=myusername
DB_PASS=mypassword
DB_NAME=mydatabase
```

I want to get only what is after `DB_PASS=` and stop at that line, ignoring the following ones.

Actual output of the `sed`:

```
$ sed -n 's/^.*DB_PASS=//p' <<< $(cat /root/dadosDB)
mypassword DB_NAME=mydatabase
```

What I need:

```
mypassword
```

Comment: Could you share with us an example of the file? [edit] the question adding it.

Comment: Done... I just edited and added more information.

Comment: How important  is your requirement to `stop at that line, ignoring the following ones`? None of the current answers do that, they all continue to read the rest of the file after finding the matching line so - do you require that because your file is particularly huge or because there might be a second `DB_PASS=mypassword` line that you don't want matched or something else? Or do you actually not need that at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this result is because you don't apply the `sed` command to the file directly, but to the result of a command substitution.

This means that the text processing is not actually applied to

```
DB_USER=myusername
DB_PASS=mypassword
DB_NAME=mydatabase
```

but to the result of the `cat` command applied to the file content, after an unquoted command substitution that squeezes the lines.

If you try

```bash
echo $(cat /root/dadosDB)
```

you will notice that the output is

```
DB_USER=myusername DB_PASS=mypassword DB_NAME=mydatabase
```

all on a single line, rather than on separate lines. If you place the command substitution in double-quotes, as in

```bash
echo "$(cat /root/datosDB)"
```

the newlines will be preserved.

The key points are that

1. you need neither the `cat` nor the command substitution, and
2. if you use the command substitution without placing it in double-quotes, you will lose the newlines (see [this Q&A e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22101778/12231187)).<sup>(1)</sup>

---

**TL;DR:**

Use

```
sed -n -e 's/^.*DB_PASS=//p' /root/dadosDB
```

or (rather)

```
sed -n -e 's/^DB_PASS=//p' /root/dadosDB
```

to exclude lines with keywords that start differently, but *end* in `DB_PASS`.

Please note: You write *"and stop at that line, ignoring the following ones."* I took this as meaning that you want to print *the word after `DB_PASS`*, but not the following lines (that technically also come after `DB_PASS`. If you mean that there could be more lines starting with `DB_PASS` and you want to ensure matching only the first, you will need a slight adjustment:

```
sed -n -e '0,/DB_PASS/s/^DB_PASS=//p' /root/dadosDB
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Note that the issue in your particular case is how your shell (I assume Bash) handles "Here-strings" with unquoted substitutions, so (as noted by @steeldriver) a better demonstration is

```
cat <<< "$(cat /root/dadosDB)"
```

vs.

```
cat <<< $(cat /root/dadosDB)
```

The behavior has [changed with Bash v4.4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288939/377345): Before, the output of the two commands was different in the same way as the `echo` examples mentioned above. In later versions of Bash, the unquoted command substitution would no longer lead to word-splitting and consequent squeezing of multi-line output.

---

If you are interested to learn more, you may want to look at

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Also, I would recommend checking your scripts with [`shellcheck`](https://shellcheck.net), also available as standalone tool on many Linux distributions, to avoid syntax (and other) errors.

Comment: @AdminBee AFAIK word splitting of unquoted expansions in here strings is not the default in other shells that support them and is no longer the default in bash >= 4.4. See for example [Why does cut fail with bash and not zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288939/65304)

Comment: @steeldriver You are right, but many Bash installations (including mine, and obviously the OP's) still seem to be pre-4.4. I will add a note, though, thanks for the notice :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `awk`, which seems (to me) a more suited option than `sed` for the task:

```bsh
$ awk -F'=' '$1 == "DB_PASS" { print $2 }' /root/dadosDB
mypassword
```

Another option is a combination of `grep` and `cut`:

```bsh
$ grep "^DB_PASS=" /root/dadosDB | cut -d= -f2
mypassword
```

Note both commands treat the input as *columns* separated by `=`.

Comment: @RaulChiarella the best approach in general is to try to use the more suited tool for the job (not that I'm telling my selection is the correct one necessarelly). Knowing a little of each parsing text tool `cut`, `grep`, `awk`, etc, can save you time and get better results.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sed -n "s/.*DB_PASS=\(.*\)/\1/p" <<< $(cat /root/dadosDB)
```

If it's just one line ->

```
echo "DB_USER=myusername DB_PASS=mypassword DB_NAME=mydatabase" | sed -n "s/.*DB_PASS=\(.*\)DB.*/\1/p"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this would give the same result as the OP's attempt because the underlying problem - applying the `sed` call to the unquoted result of a command substitution rather then the file content - is not solved.

Comment: Didnt work. Thanks tho...

Comment: Wow. echo "DB_USER=myusername DB_PASS=mypassword DB_NAME=mydatabase" | sed -n "s/.*DB_PASS=\(.*\)DB.*/\1/p"
Just for fun.....

Comment: I copy-and-pasted your example command, and the result was the same as what the OP posted as "unwanted output" (i.e. `mypassword DB_NAME=mydatabase`)

Comment: The comment field "eat" the backslash....

Comment: Regarding `sed -n "s/.*DB_PASS=\(.*\)/\1/p"` - don't use double quotes around strings (including scripts) unless you **need** to, use single quotes instead. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. Regarding `$(cat /root/dadosDB)` that will concatenate the whole input file onto 1 line, you do need double quotes around that, `"$(cat /root/dadosDB)"` but it'd be more concise as just `sed '...' < <(cat /root/dadosDB)` or `sed '...' < '/root/dadosDB'` or just a plain old `sed '...' '/root/dadosDB'`

Comment: The `echo | sed` command isn't useful as it's not what the OP needs to do (operate on a file) and it's very fragile, e.g. try `echo 'DB_USER=myusername DB_PASS=mypassword DB_NAME=mydatabase DB_FOO=bar' | sed -n 's/.*DB_PASS=(.*)DB.*/\1/p'`